# Importancia de unset() PHP

Tags: php

Aprendiendo PHP me he topado con los bucles `foreach` y por lo tanto con la función `unset()`, leyendo la documentación no me ha quedado nada claro el por qué es una buena práctica hacer de su uso al terminar el bucle. Muchas gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 1):

Probablemente te topaste con un [ejemplo asi](https://php.net/manual/es/language.references.pass.php):

```
<?php
$array = [1, 2, 3, 4];
foreach ($array as &$valor) {
    $valor = $valor * 2;
}
// $array ahora es [2, 4, 6, 8]
unset($valor); // rompe la referencia con el último elemento
?>
```

Al agregar `&` antes de `$valor` este se convierte en un [pase por referencia](https://php.net/manual/es/language.references.pass.php) significa que en vez de pasar el contenido de la variable estas pasando su referencia en memoria.

Por lo cual en este ejemplo `$valor` continuara estando definido luego de terminar el ciclo.

Entonces si no usas `unset($valor);` este continuara teniendo la referencia de `$array[3]` por ejemplo si luego de este ciclo haces `echo $valor;` el resultado sera `8`

El problema con esto es que si posteriomente usas `$valor` sin haber usando `unset()` afectaras a `$array[3]`

```
<?php
$array = [1, 2, 3, 4];
foreach ($array as &$valor) {
    $valor = $valor * 2;
}
// $array ahora es [2, 4, 6, 8]
print_r($array);
echo ' ';
echo $valor;
$valor++;
echo ' ';
// $array ahora es [2, 4, 6, 9]
print_r($array);
unset($valor); // rompe la referencia con el último elemento
echo ' ';
echo $valor;
?>
```

Sin pase por referencia:

```
<?php
$array = [1, 2, 3, 4];
foreach ($array as $valor) {
    $valor = $valor * 2;
}
print_r($array);
echo ' ';
echo $valor;
// $array se queda igual [1, 2, 3, 4] porque no le asignaste ningun valor nuevo, se los asignaste a $valor
$valor++;
unset($valor); // rompe la referencia con el último elemento
echo ' ';
echo $valor;
?>
```

Comment: Claro, el puntero se queda en `array[3]`. Por lo tanto ¿si no hace hace un paso por referencia no se debe de usar `unset()`?. Por último ¿aunque no se haga por referencia es una buena práctica implementarlo en el código?

Comment: Complemente un poco más la respuesta.

Comment: Es opcional pero una buena práctica hacerlo porque luego del ciclo $valor ya no te sirve para nada (depende de lo que quieras hacer) y así liberas memoria.